The buttons in my roblox tycoon dont work
me and my friend are making a tycoon by following a tutorial but standing on a button doesnt create the dropper, this is what my friend scripted;

the droppers and conveyors  and buttons have the Id and Idofitemtounlock but they already spawn when u join the game

Welcome. Please edit to post your code as formatted text rather than a screenshot.
Some of the many reasons to post errors/code as text include making your question more searchable and more accessible for folks using screen readers or translation software, so you get access to more experts who can help you. The {} icon above the editing window generally handles most code formatting. If you need more info you can check our formatting guide &/or add a comment asking for formatting help.
